# Truecrypt wholedisk encryption with no partitions?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, truecrypt

I cleaned a 8TB harddisk using Diskpart. So now the disk is partitionless with just the online/uninitialized status. Under Truecrypt wholedisk encryption menu bowever. The disk was found as a disknumber and I was able to choose it instead of a partition. And set it up as wholedisk encrypted drive. Mount and unmount is fine. I've written a bunch of data to it to test and it seems OK. BUT. **Will I encoounter any known issues seting up a wholedisk encrypted device like this?**
Usually I had to select a partition on a device/disk/usb to mount. Now I choose just the whole disk.

Second question. I read that every disk larger than 2.2TB needs GPT partitioning to be able to utilize 2.2> disks. So **how was my Truecrypt able to format my 8TB disk as NTFS but not create any GPT partitioning on the disk. Or did it actually do it?**

Comment: Quote from `diskpart`'s `help clean`: _"If the ALL parameter is not used, the first 1MB and the last 1MB of the disk are zeroed."_. It's just writing zeros to the areas where partition table is stored.

Comment: @gronostaj HI I that's not what I meant, but I wasn't clear enough that is my fault. I changed my post.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an abandoned software (for ~9 years) that has known vulnerabilities? I strongly recommend to switch to Truecrypt successor VeraCrypt. It has been checked in multiple code reviews.

Comment: Yep. TC worked before it got abandoned and I do not trust Veractypt. It's just the way it is. The maker went to work for Microsoft. So there. Can you answer my questions?